# How to set a background pattern for a large UIScrollView (that scrolls with the view)

Tags: ios, uiview, uiscrollview, core-animation, core-graphics

Seems like a very simple problem! But I'm having great difficulty.

My ideas and attempts so far:

1. `scrollView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:myImage]]`

   - ***Doesn't scroll with contents***
2. Create `UIView` the size of `contentSize` (actually, larger due to elastic bounces on scroll view), and use pattern as above on this sub view of `UIScrollView`.

   - ***Causes massive memory hit (and crash) when UIView gets too large.*** See also: [Large UIScrollView with background pattern fails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5204434/large-uiscrollview-with-background-pattern-fails)
3. Similar to (2), exept I only create a `UIView` the size of the maximum number of repetitions of the background image that will be seen, and cleverly move the view to wherever is needed to show the correct background repetitions.

   - ***Causes this background view to shift left and right unexpectedly when animating the scroll.***
4. Create `UIView` subclass and override `drawRect`. Use various Core Graphics techniques to draw content by hand.

   - ***Not animatable. Implementing my own*** `contentOffset` ***property isn't a standard Core Animation property.***
   - ***Overriding*** `drawRect` ***on*** `UIScrollView` ***doesn't respect the content offset, and doesn't get called multiple times as it scrolls/animates. The rect parameter is always simply the bounds of the*** `UIScrollView`.
5. As with (4), except I set the `bounds.origin` of my `UIView` subclass in my `setContentOffset` implementation, since it's an animatable property.

   - `drawRect` ***doesn't seem to get called every frame.***
6. Use `CATiledLayer`, as suggested in this answer: [Large UIScrollView with background pattern fails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5204434/large-uiscrollview-with-background-pattern-fails). Implementation details here: http://www.cimgf.com/2011/03/01/subduing-catiledlayer/.

   - ***I really don't want the ugliness of seeing tiles asynchronously being drawn as user scrolls. It's just a simple background pattern!***

This seems like the simplest thing! Why is it so hard!?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe the sample code:ScollViewSuit->3_Tiling can help you. You can search it in the official docset.

This works like CATiledLayer but only use UIKit, the tile was loaded on the main thread.

And I really don't think this is a good solution.

Comment: Thanks Kwok. I think this is looking like the best answer so far. I wonder if it's possible to get this working without any fade in at all for the tiles? If so, I might go the whole hog and make use of the fact that I'm using the tech, and make a massive tiling background - turn it into a real feature!

Comment: Ah, sorry didn't realise that their tiling example doesn't use `CATiledLayer`, and instead uses multiple `UIImageViews` Think I might give the technique a go...

Comment: Okay, marked as correct solution since I decided to go ahead with it, despite being far from simple!